# qplot call overwrites list elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

Running the R script

```
list1<-list()
list2<-list()

for(i in 1:3){
  list1[[i]]<-i
}

for(i in 1:3){
  list2[[i]]<-qplot(i)
}
```

I recognize that list1 contains the elements 1,2,3. But list2 contains three times the element qplot(3).

Is qplot not compatible with looping? How can I save my plots in a list using a loop?

Comment: @David Arenburg: Mh, my problem is not printing, but saving. For me, the code from the question you pointed to, already prints 3 different graphs in RStudio - without adding dev.new()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ggplot` the aesthetics are stored as expressions and evaluated when the plot is rendered. So `qplot(i)` does *not* generate a plot, but rather a *plot definition*, using a reference to the variable `i`. All three plots are the same in the sense that they all reference `i`.

If you type

```
list2[[1]]
```

after the second loop has run, you cause the `ggplot` object stored in `list2[[1]]` to be rendered, using whatever value `i` is set to at the moment (which is 3 after the loop).

Try this:

```
i <- 4
list2[[1]]
```

Now the plot rendered is equivalent to `qplot(4)`.

The workaround depends on what you are trying to achieve. The basic idea is not to use external variables in aesthetics. So in your trivial case,

```
for(i in 1:3){
  list2[[i]]<-ggplot(data.frame(x=i), aes(x))+geom_histogram()
}
```

will work. This is because the reference to the external variable `i` is *not* in the aesthetics (e.g., the call to `aes(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. The difference in handling the dataframe and the aesthetics still seems a bit counter-intuitive. But keeping that in mind I can at least create lists of plots for variable dataframes, which already solves my problem.

Comment: It's *completely* counter-intuitive, hopelessly abstruse, and utterly infuriating. What's worse, since `qplot(...)` is a wrapper for the more complex `ggplot(...)` calls, you don't really know when it's using `aes(...)` and when not. My advice is: 1 - give up on `qplot(...)` and just learn `ggplot`, and 2 - try to avoid putting any external references into the calls to `aes(...)`.